# dropdown in navbar on smartphone

Tags: html

I have a problem with the navbar when displayed on a smartphone.
The last item of the menu is a dropdown. It is not displayed unless I enlarge the screen. It is as if there was no more space to display the items of the submenu (while the other dropdwons work perfecty).
Could somebody tell me what mistake I did ? Here is the code:

```
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <a class="pull-left"><img src="logo_navbar.png" alt="logo"></a><div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Associazione</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="chisiamo.html" title="Chi siamo">Chi siamo</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="struttura.html" title="struttura">Struttura</a>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="statuto.html" title="statuto">Statuto</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Bilancio Sociale</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="bilancio2015_16.html" title="bilancio2016">Bilancio 2015-2016</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="bilancio2014_15.html" title="bilancio2015">Bilancio 2014-2015</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="bilancio2013_14.html" title="bilancio2014">Bilancio 2013-2014</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="bilancio2012_13.html" title="bilancio2013">Bilancio 2012-2013</a>
                                </li>
                              </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="gara.html" title="gara">Gara di matematica</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="news.html" title="news">News</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="rassegnastampa.html" title="stampa">Rassegna stampa</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="modulo.html" title="iscrizione">Iscrizione</a>
                        </li>
                          <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Contatti</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="contatti.html" title="messaggi">Messaggi</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="dovesiamo.html" title="dove siamo">Dove siamo</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="newsletter.html" title="newsletter">Newsletter</a>
                                </li>
                              </ul>
                        </li>

                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

Thank you very much in advance
gabriele

Comment: its working. [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/xgvb3vtd/ ] click on the last one.. overflow will show your submenu

Comment: I can't see any "overflow" inside the code you wrote !

Comment: Bootstrap already set the scroll option by default.

Comment: I understood what is the problem. In reality, as you said, my navbar works BUT no scroll bar is shown on the smartphone. Nevertheless if I use the finger to scroll up the page the dropdown appears ! I don't have a smartphone therefore I know nothing about it... Why is it not possible to show the scrollbar on the dropdown menu ??? Thanks a lot

Comment: [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/85d0I.png ] see this iPhone 5 scroll bar when click

Answer (score 0):

Your code works:

https://jsfiddle.net/8c8x558e/

I think the problem would be your bootstrap links, remember you have to put these links:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I think you forgot the Js link.

Comment: This is what I wrote into the head section:

Comment: This is what I wrote into the head section                                                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: I'm not sure if javascript tags works inside head section... Try to put them inside body tag, it's prefered to put at the end of the content. It's explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup

Answer (score 0):

Remove this css in mobile view  .navbar-fixed-top  {position: fixed;}

you can use {position: static;}

Comment: And how this will solve the problem? if i set .navbar-fixed-top{position: static;} ?? Can you explain please ?

Comment: yes you can use media query in css file here is demo @media (max-width:767px) {
 
  .navbar-fixed-top{position: static;}
  
}

Comment: How position static will solve the problem mate??  Explain please

Comment: here is a live demo for you [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/oowt44y9/1/ ] Now explain me.

Comment: if you are using position:fixed than you can no able to scroll that's why use position static or position absolute

Comment: position fixed nav will move when you scroll the body section. If we set static then it will not move with scroll. :) I hope you got my point

Answer (score 0):

Also use class="caret" where the is a sub-menu to make sure there is a sub-menu I used it after the text "Contatti". For any question ask me in comment. [LiveONFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/xgvb3vtd/1/) :)

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <a class="pull-left"><img src="logo_navbar.png" alt="logo"></a>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Associazione</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="chisiamo.html" title="Chi siamo">Chi siamo</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="struttura.html" title="struttura">Struttura</a>
              <li>
                <a href="statuto.html" title="statuto">Statuto</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Bilancio Sociale</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="bilancio2015_16.html" title="bilancio2016">Bilancio 2015-2016</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="bilancio2014_15.html" title="bilancio2015">Bilancio 2014-2015</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="bilancio2013_14.html" title="bilancio2014">Bilancio 2013-2014</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="bilancio2012_13.html" title="bilancio2013">Bilancio 2012-2013</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="gara.html" title="gara">Gara di matematica</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="news.html" title="news">News</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="rassegnastampa.html" title="stampa">Rassegna stampa</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="modulo.html" title="iscrizione">Iscrizione</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Contatti <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="contatti.html" title="messaggi">Messaggi</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="dovesiamo.html" title="dove siamo">Dove siamo</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="newsletter.html" title="newsletter">Newsletter</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!--/.nav-collapse -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```